# mySQL -problem grouping and returning correct values using GROUP BY / HAVING

Tags: mysql

I have a crossReference table (crossref_room_subject) with conference room, meeting subject and timeSlot IDs.  There are multiple entries per timeSlot.  The subjectCode table includes a subjectCodeCategory ID also (only one category per subject but multiple subjects per category).  For one query that is working, the user is entering multiple subjectCodes and I need to return the timeSlots where all subjectCodes exist.  I am now getting good results (thanks again Sparky) using GROUP BY and HAVING but all the information needed for this query in the one table:  crossref_room_subject.

I have one last scenario that uses more variables and I can't get it to work.  This time the user enters multiple subjectCodeCategorys.  I have to link to the subjectCodes table to crossreference subjectCodeCategory with the subjectCode.  I have tried it a bunch of ways, mostly changing the SELECT and/or GROUP BY, this seems to be where I should be able to group those subjectCodeCategories.  But it is not working (see below).  I am getting returns for each timeSlot that has 3 returns--good except it only counts subjectCode, regardless of subjectCodeCategory.  I need to return only those timeSlots where one (or more) of each of the three subjectCodeCategories is represented.  I have tried adding subjectCodeCategory to the SELECT and/or GROUP BY clauses but don't get any better results.

Thanks for any help or ideas in advance.
Grey

SELECT a.meetingID, a.timeSlot
FROM crossref_room_subject a , subjectCodes b
WHERE a.subjectID = b.subjectID
AND (
b.subjectCodeCategory =8
OR b.subjectCodeCategory =19
OR b.subjectCodeCategory =23
)
GROUP BY a.meetingID, a.timeSlot
HAVING COUNT( * ) =3
LIMIT 0 , 30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  This gives the results I need:

```
SELECT a.meetingID, a.timeSlot 
FROM crossref_room_subject a , subjectCodes b 
WHERE a.subjectID = b.subjectID 
AND ( b.subjectCodeCategory =8 OR b.subjectCodeCategory =19 OR b.subjectCodeCategory =23 ) 
GROUP BY a.meetingID, a.timeSlot 
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT b.subjectCodeCategory ) =3 LIMIT 0 , 30
```